# grunt-code-coverage-enforcer doesn't fail on threshhold limits

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, code-coverage

I'm running Jasmine tests and Karma coverage to generate an lcov file. I can see in the coverage reports and console that there is poor line coverage on a number of JavaScript files.

```
------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
File                                |   % Stmts |% Branches |   % Funcs |   % Lines |
------------------------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
   ./src/accountDetails/controller\ |      9.09 |       100 |         0 |      9.09 |
      AccountDetailsController.js   |      9.09 |       100 |         0 |      9.09 |
```

Istanbul isn't stopping the grunt process, so I added grunt-code-coverage-enforcer. The configuration looks like this:

```
  'code-coverage-enforcer': { /* doesn't seem to work either */
    options: {
      lcovfile: "build/lcov/PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)/lcov.info",
        lines: 99,
        functions: 99,
        branches: 99,
        src: "src",
        includes: ['src/**/*.js'],
        excludes: []
    }
  }
```

I'm pretty sure the enforcer is running, because initially it wasn't finding the lcov.info file. If I run the enforcer task with --verbose, I see this (Removed a lot of extraneous stuff, like it reiterates the input options, which look correct):

```
Reading the lcov file ....
Processing File:build/lcov/PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)/lcov.info
Checking if file exists ... build/lcov/PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)/lcov.info
processing callback with [
  {
    "file": "./src/accountDetails/controller/AccountDetailsController.js",
    "lines": {
      "found": 11,
      "hit": 1
    },
    "functions": {
      "hit": 0,
      "found": 3
    },
    "branches": {
      "hit": 0,
      "found": 0
    }
  }
]
------------------------------------------------------------------
Scanning folder for files
------------------------------------------------------------------
Collecting directory:src\accountDetails\controller
------------------------------------------------------------------
Threshold configuration: lines:99%, functions:99%, branches:99%
------------------------------------------------------------------
File:./src/accountDetails/controller/AccountDetailsController.js
lines:9.09% | functions:100% | branches:100% | >> EXCLUDED
Done, without errors.
```

So my questions are:

- Is this correct?
- What is the >> EXCLUDED in the output all about?
- Is this enforcer task supposed to fail my build process?
- Can I make it fail my build process (or am I misinterpreting what code coverage enforcement in a JavaScript app is for) ????????????

Comment: To add to the mystery, the enforcer does fail the build on Hudson/Linux, but not on Windows 7. So although failing the build works on the CI/CD environment, ideally it would behave the same way on developers' machines.

Comment: And now to add to the mystery, I realize the Linux is breaking even if I set minimal coverage. So I set coverage to 5, 5, 5, but see this in the output:
`lines:66.67% | functions:100% | branches:100% | >> EXCLUDED`
`File:./src/accountDetails/controller/AccountDetailsController.js`

`>> FAILED file:src/accountDetails/controller/AccountDetailsController.js :: Has no code coverage data. Ensure that the source file is represented in test coverage (lcov) data`

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a pull request at https://github.com/tapasvimoturu/grunt-code-coverage-enforcer/pull/2 that should fix this. Hopefully the author will accept the request soon and republish the project to npm.